# Apache Camel + RabbitMQ. Endpoint not creating

Tags: java, rabbitmq, apache-camel

I have created project, that contains only route settings for rabbitmq.

```
<route>
    <from uri="rabbitmq:localhost/test_out_ex?queue=test_out&amp;autoDelete=false&amp;username=admin&amp;password=admin"/>
    <to uri="rabbitmq:localhost/test_in_ex?queue=test_in&amp;autoDelete=false&amp;username=admin&amp;password=admin"/>
</route>
```

I run it on tomcat and Camel creates only "from"-endpoint, not "to" (I look it in rabbitMq web interface). Why? Because, "to" hasn't got consumers?

more details:

Problem is messages aren't saved in output message queue. It's a normal situation, when application has send message to queue, which hasn't got consumer online at this time, so it should save message, until consumer connects.

So, I defined simple route and deploy it on tomcat, also I deployed Jolokia project to monitor my camel context via Hawtio. Hawtio shows me, that route is created and consists of two endpoints. Then I publish message via RabbitMq web-interface to 'test_out'. Hawtio shows me, that it reaches 'test_in' queue, but in RabbitMq web-interface (or rabbitmqctl) 'test_in' queue doesn't exists, so after server restarts message gone.

Comment: Spend more time looking into this, and then only post here when you have more details!

Answer (score 2):

We need to filter the message headers which could cause some trouble when routing from the test_out to test_in.

```
<route>
    <from uri="rabbitmq:localhost/test_out_ex?queue=test_out&amp;autoDelete=false&amp;username=admin&amp;password=admin"/>
    <removeHeader pattern="rabbitmq.*"/>
    <to uri="rabbitmq:localhost/test_in_ex?queue=test_in&amp;autoDelete=false&amp;username=admin&amp;password=admin"/>
</route>
```

Comment: Could you explain why do we need to remove the header?

Comment: Because camel supports to override some setting such as the queue from the message header, so we need to use remove them to avoid sending the message back to the test_in. If you don't want to remove the headers that way, you can set the option bridgeEndpoint to be true since camel-2.12.3. It just tell camel to ignore the setting from the message headers.

Comment: This should be marked as the solution. I've spent the better half of a day trying to figure this out!! Turns out that the headers of the inbound message specified an EXCHANGE_NAME which I then believe is overriding the exchange specified in the outbound message URN.